# querying users with whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("updatedAt", date)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to fetch all users from Parse database with the following query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ONLY);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();        
calendar.roll(Calendar.DATE, false); // roll one day back       
Date date = calendar.getTime();        
query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("updatedAt", date);
```

but I am always getting empty list.

Please advise how to fetch the users with the given date criteria for the "updatedAt" key.

The analogous code in Objective-C works like a charm:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
NSTimeInterval A_DAY_AGO = -1 * 24* 60 * 60; // in seconds
[query whereKey:@"updatedAt" greaterThanOrEqualTo:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: A_DAY_AGO]];
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried also the following but with no success:

```
long DAY_IN_MS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - DAY_IN_MS);
query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("updatedAt", date);
```

**EDIT2:**

I have finally found out what went wrong - the issue was not caused by the query returning empty list but by some other bug in my code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the Date object you are creating to see if it is the value you are expecting?

Comment: I have just tried to debug the Date object as recommended and found the both versions of code are working now what I don't understand and need to investigate further. The only thing which seems  to be suspicious to me is that the code was not working when I tested it on Saturday the first time, and today's when it's working is Sunday - might be some strange effect of the "calendar.roll(Calendar.DATE, false);" calculation? I guess the "new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - DAY_IN_MS)" should not have any such effects???

Comment: I have tested the Calendar roll() methods and everything works correctly also when rolling back from the last day of week - no idea what went wrong...

Comment: Glad the code has started working. I'm sure you've already checked this, but are you sure there were objects with an updated Date between the time on saturday and 24 hours before?.Also I can't remember if Calendar uses a local timezone or UTC time, but Parse uses UTC, So if Calendar uses a local timezone then there could be an offset between your time and Parses time

Comment: Yes I am sure there where some objects with updatedAT passing the query criteria.